# InfluxDB get moving min/max

Tags: range, influxdb, sliding-window

InfluxDB provides [movingAverage() or timedMovingAverage()](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/query-data/flux/moving-average/), but what is the most efficient way to get the moving min/max?

For example, if I have data like:

| _time | _value |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01 | -1 |
| 01-02 | 4 |
| 01-03 | 2 |
| 01-04 | 9 |
| 01-05 | -4 |
| 01-06 | 3 |
| 01-07 | 8 |
| 01-08 | 1 |

The following would return:

```
|> movingMinMax(n: 3) or |> timedMovingMinMax(every: 3d, period: 8d)
```

| _time | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-03 | -1 | 4 |
| 01-04 | 2 | 9 |
| 01-05 | -4 | 9 |
| 01-06 | -4 | 9 |
| 01-07 | -4 | 8 |
| 01-08 | 1 | 8 |